# Is there a simple way to alter core node/add/my_node_type to adding/my_node_type?

Tags: 7, path-aliases

I don't want to show "node/add" in my url "node/add/my_node_type", instead I want to have "adding/my_node_type". Is there a simple way to hide "node/add" but not loose those args?
I want to have "node/add/my_node_type" functionality after hitting "adding/my_node_type".

I can't see form add or form edit patterns in path so I think it is not so easy...

Of course after that I will need "node/%/edit" to be "editing/%"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't test this code, but if I'm not mistaken, it should be as simple as doing this in a custom module:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_NAME_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['adding/my-node-type'] = $items['node/add/my-node-type'];
  unset($items['node/add/my-node-type']);
}
```

Something similar could be done for the editing path.

Comment: unset did what I want. I thought that it's not working, cause I forgot to rebuild cache...

Answer (score 2):

I would do this like so:

create a new module and in this module declare:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_NAME_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['node/add/your-content-type-name']['page-callback'] = 'drupal_not_found';
}
```

this will override default page callback for your content type and will return 404 page

Then declare pages you need:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_NAME_menu() {
   $items = array();
   $items['adding/your-content-type-name'] = array(
     'title' => 'Add new your content type name instance',
     'page callback' => 'your_content_type_name_page_callback',
     'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
     'access callback' => TRUE // or whatever you think the access callback should be for this content type
   );
   $items['editing/%'] = array(
     'title' => 'Edit your content type name instance',
     'page callback' => 'your_content_type_name_page_callback',
     'page arguments' => array(2),
     'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
     'access callback' => TRUE // or whatever you think the access callback should be for this content type
   );
}
```

Declare a callback that will be serving the node edit form:

```
function your_content_type_name_page_callback($nid = FALSE) {
   $node = node_load($nid);
   if($node) {
     if($node->type == 'your_content_type_name') {
       $form = drupal_get_form('your_content_type_name_node_form', $node);
       return drupal_render($form);
     }
   }
   return drupal_not_found();
}
```

I did pretty much similar task in one of my previous projects, so I am sure this approach will work out. May be there are other ways to accomplish what you are after.

Comment: In D7 $node = node_load($nid) in function your_content_type_name_page_callback can be ommited with $items['editing/%node'] = ... but I'm getting error while drupal_get_form is executed. Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'node_form' not found or invalid function name w drupal_retrieve_form(). It looks like node_form is not accessible inside.

Comment: your_content_type_name_page_callback seems not right for new content, as when there is no $nid, function will just go to page not found, right?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't expect, but I can simply make path alias from **node/add/my_node_type**
to **whatever/i/need**. Just one click here http://www.example.com/admin/config/search/path/add. No coding, no custom module. All I have to check is how about args - theoretically 'node/add/my_node_type' (3 args path) can be aliased to 'whatever' (looks like 1 arg, but is it?) or 'what/ever/and/ever' (looks like 4 args).